# Find .jpg's in 2 different folders with same name and same LastWriteDate

Tags: powershell

I have many jpg's on a hardrive which are the same pictures. 
Now I'd like to find them. Therefore I need to compare 2 folders and find the pictures which are the same.
I want to find the pictures with the same name AND the same LastWriteTime.
One of the criterias is not enough.
So, I need a Powershell code which could do that.
Here is what I have but it doesnt work well. I got also results which werent't correct.

Thats what I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Pfad1 -Recurse -Filter *jpg |
    Where-Object {(Get-ChildItem -Path $Pfad2 -Recurse -Filter *jpg) -match $_.Name -and $_.LastWriteTime} | 
        ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without recursion you can compare the folders files with `Compare-Object`

```
$Folder1 = 'X:\path'
$Folder2 = 'Y:\path'

$Files1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder1 -Filter *.jpg
$Files2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder2 -Filter *.jpg

Compare-Object -Ref $Files1 -Diff $Files2 -Property Name,LastWriteTime `
    -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru
```

If recursion is required and the subfolder has to be compared also you'll have to build a calculated property with the relative path to be comparable.